# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. con parametro en Procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

tengo este procedimiento almacenado donde recibo por medio de un parámetro tipo varchar unos números de identificación para unos documentos separados por coma, que servirán como filtro para el query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_DescDocum

@NrosDoc varchar(MAX)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 

'SELECT D.IdDocumento, D.NroRegistro, D.NroDcumento, D.TipoDocumento, TP.DescripcionDocum, 
    LP.YearRegistro, ''N/T'' AS Periodo  FROM tbl_Documentos D
    INNER JOIN tbl_TipoDocumentos TP
    ON D.IdTipoDocum = TP.IdTipoDocum
    INNER JOIN tbl_RegistroDocum LP
    ON D.IdRegistro = LP.IdRegistro
WHERE D.NroDocumento IN (' + @NrosDoc + ')'

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

El problema ocurre cuando ejecuto el procedimiento almacenado me manda estos dos errores

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

¿Cual es la forma correcta de mandar el parámetro?

Comment: Imagino que el campo `NroDocumento` es de tipo `INT`, y tu estas recibiendo un listado de numeros como `String` (varchar); debes realizar la conversion de los numeros en el backend o en el procedimiento

Comment: El campo era varchar pero estaba ocurriendo lo contrario, estaba pasando a un entero en lugar de un string jajaj que pena de verdad

Comment: Excelente! Si pudiste solucionarlo deja tu respuesta para posibles casos parecidos. Feliz Código!

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar crea esta function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String nvarchar(max), @Delimiter char(1))       
    returns @temptable TABLE (item varchar(8000), id int identity(1,1))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
          ,@slice nvarchar(max);

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return;       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String;       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(item) values(@slice);       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx);      
        if len(@String) = 0 break;       
    end;   
return;       
end;
```

Y aplica este cambio en tu sp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_DescDocum

@NrosDoc varchar(MAX)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 

'SELECT D.IdDocumento, D.NroRegistro, D.NroDcumento, D.TipoDocumento, TP.DescripcionDocum, 
    LP.YearRegistro, ''N/T'' AS Periodo  FROM tbl_Documentos D
    INNER JOIN tbl_TipoDocumentos TP
    ON D.IdTipoDocum = TP.IdTipoDocum
    INNER JOIN tbl_RegistroDocum LP
    ON D.IdRegistro = LP.IdRegistro
WHERE D.NroDocumento IN (select cast(item as int) from dbo.Split('''+@NrosDoc+''','+''','''+'))

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```